# How to get multi-touch working correctly with JWinPointer in libGDX?

Tags: java, windows, libgdx, multi-touch

I'm working on a simple cooperative game for two players running on a widescreen touch display. I use libGDX as a base for the game and have Windows as a target platform. The problem is that libGDX doesn't support multi-touch for Windows, so its GestureListener doesn't work there. I tried to do a workaround and found a multi-touch library called [JWinPointer](http://www.michaelmcguffin.com/code/JWinPointer/), which bridges Java with Windows .NET API. I managed to get multi-touch working but dragging my game actor causes a delay in his movement (the longer I drag him, the slower he moves following the path I "drew" with my finger). Dragging multiple actors (shapes) at once makes delays even longer. From what I know, my code should be OK and the delay is probably caused by the library itself. It looks like the JWinPointer listener reports a new touch pointer for every pixel or game frame, which could be also a part of the problems, as my application can't keep up (I execute the movement method for each reported pointer which has a different position than the previous one).

Each detected pointer is saved into an ArrayList and only updated if detected pointerID already exists in the list. I also use HashMap to save a pointer touching the certain actor and use it in my `drag()` method to decide which actor should be moved. I also use another HashMap to know if each actor has already been moved in the current frame (this was just an attempt to get rid of the delay and didn't help). I know my code probably isn't optimal and is maybe confusing but I've been working on finding a solution for this for almost a week and trying lots of things. Sorry for that.

**Here is the JWinPointer listener method:**

```
public void pointerXYEvent(int deviceType, int pointerID, int eventType, boolean inverted, int x, int y, int pressure) {
    pointerInfoArray.updatePointer( deviceType, pointerID, inverted, x, y, pressure );

    System.out.println("PointerXYEvent: " + deviceType + " " + pointerID + " " + eventType);

    takeAction(deviceType, pointerID, eventType, x, y);
}
```

**This is where I decide which action should be taken based on the touch input:**

```
private void takeAction(int deviceType, int pointerID, int eventType, int x, int y) {
    Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
    camera.unproject(touchPos);

    switch (eventType) {
        case EVENT_TYPE_DRAG :
            System.out.println("POINTER EVENT DRAG");

            for (int i=0; i<pointerInfoArray.array.size(); i++) {
                if (pointerInfoArray.array.get(i).pointerID == pointerID) {
                    PointerInfo currentPointer = pointerInfoArray.array.get(i);

                    if (currentPointer.previousX == -1 && currentPointer.previousY == -1) {
                        currentPointer.previousX = x;
                        currentPointer.previousY = y;
                        break;
                    }

                    int deltaX, deltaY;

                    if (currentPointer.previousX - x != 0 || currentPointer.previousY - y != 0) {
                        deltaX = x - currentPointer.previousX;
                        deltaY = y - currentPointer.previousY;

                        currentPointer.previousX = x;
                        currentPointer.previousY = y;

                        drag(pointerID, (float) x, (float) y, (float) deltaX, (float) deltaY);
                    }
                }
            }

            break;
        case EVENT_TYPE_HOVER :
            break;
        case EVENT_TYPE_DOWN :
            System.out.println("POINTER EVENT TOUCHDOWN");
            for (GameShape shape : shapeList) {
                if (!(shape instanceof GameCircle)) {
                    if (shape.getPolygonBounds().contains(touchPos.x, touchPos.y)) {
                        System.out.println("TOUCHING " + shape + " " + pointerID);
                        hashMap.put(shape, pointerID);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (shape.getCircle().contains(touchPos.x, touchPos.y)) {
                        System.out.println("TOUCHING " + shape + " " + pointerID);
                        hashMap.put(shape, pointerID);
                    }
                }
            }
            touchDown(x, y, pointerID, 0);
            break;
        case EVENT_TYPE_UP :
            System.out.println("POINTER EVENT TOUCHUP");
            for (GameShape shape : shapeList) {
                if (!(shape instanceof GameCircle)) {
                    if (shape.getPolygonBounds().contains(touchPos.x, touchPos.y)) {
                        System.out.println("REMOVING " + shape + " " + pointerID);
                        hashMap.remove(shape);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (shape.getCircle().contains(touchPos.x, touchPos.y)) {
                        System.out.println("REMOVING " + shape + " " + pointerID);
                        hashMap.remove(shape);
                    }
                }
            }

            pointerInfoArray.removePointer(deviceType, pointerID);
            ip.touchUp(x, y, pointerID, 0);

            for (int i=0; i<pointerInfoArray.array.size(); i++) {
                if (pointerInfoArray.array.get(i).pointerID == pointerID) {
                    pointerInfoArray.array.get(i).previousX = -1;
                    pointerInfoArray.array.get(i).previousY = -1;
                }
            }

            break;
        case EVENT_TYPE_BUTTON_DOWN :
            break;
        case EVENT_TYPE_BUTTON_UP :
            break;
        case EVENT_TYPE_IN_RANGE :
            break;
        case EVENT_TYPE_OUT_OF_RANGE :
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**And this is where I actually move the actor (shape):**

```
public void drag(int pointer, float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
            Vector3 panPos = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
            camera.unproject(panPos);

        Iterator it = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            if (pair.getValue().equals(pointer)) {
                GameShape shape = (GameShape) pair.getKey();
                if (!frameMap.get(shape)) {
                    if (!(shape instanceof GameCircle)) {
                        if ((shape.getPolygonBounds().contains(panPos.x, panPos.y) && shape.getTouched()) || shape.getTouched()) {
                            shape.getPolygonBounds().setPosition(shape.getPolygonBounds().getX() + deltaX, shape.getPolygonBounds().getY() - deltaY);
                            shape.getPolygonSprite().setPosition(shape.getPolygonSprite().getX() + deltaX, shape.getPolygonSprite().getY() - deltaY);
                            frameMap.put(shape, true);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ((shape.getCircle().contains(panPos.x, panPos.y) && shape.getTouched()) || shape.getTouched()) {
                            shape.getCircle().setPosition(shape.getCircle().x + deltaX, shape.getCircle().y - deltaY);
                            shape.getCircleSprite().setPosition(shape.getCircleSprite().getX() + deltaX, shape.getCircleSprite().getY() - deltaY);
                            frameMap.put(shape, true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Do you see anything wrong with my code that should possibly cause the movement delay? Also, if you know about another way or library to do this, let me know, please (as far as I know, JavaFX isn't an option for me). I'm out of ideas. Thank you.

**EDIT**
I managed to solve the problem by setting libGDX to use non-continuous rendering and calling the render after each actor's position change. However, this solved the problem only for running the application in fullscreen mode. There is still delay in windowed mode.

Comment: If your assumption is correct, that handling multiple touch input events causes a delay because your code cannot keep up, then most likely you are updating the screen too often. We cannot see the code that interleaves event handling and triggering updates. In general, you will have to expect delays with touch input, e.g. because the system cannot send click events prior to the long-press timeout, or to filter out unwanted input. JWinPointer probably doesn't suffer from the former, but most likely won't give you access to control the latter.